Adding methods to a dictionary using decorator inheritance
I have been experimenting with some decorators and how they are inherited. The thing I am trying to do is create a decorator that can be inherited by another class that will add the method to a dictionary within this class.
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = {}

    def Appenddict(key):
        def _Appenddict(function):

            # I want to add to the dictionary here so i dont have to call the method

            def wrapper(*args):
                self = args[0]
                self.mydict[key] = function
                return function
            return wrapper
        return _Appenddict
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        A.__init__(self)

    @A.Appenddict("Key1")
    def MyMethod(self):
        print("My Method")

B1 = B()
print(B1.mydict)
B1.MyMethod()
print(B1.mydict)

The code above shows my attempt at creating such a system. It is capable of achieving this, but it requires calling the method, which is something I do not want. Any ideas?

Hey, not sure what you want to do, but if you don't want to call the function maybe you can use the constructor of the B class to set that key in the super class. something like this: super(B, self).__init__(key="key1") and in A constructor you call your function, or just add to self.mydict

Hi @Aleti the goal is that when B inherits A that every method that has this decorator on top of it is added to the  dictionary with a given key. And this works when you run my code. But only when you call the method and this is because it is within wrapper and wrapper is only fired when the method is called. I want to add the method to the dictionary without having to call the method. But when you try this you run into the problem that self is not accessiblein _Appenddict. So my question could also be rewriten as how do i access self within _Appenddict.

Have you tried to make Appenddict a classmethod? This way you will have access to cls, and can do something like this: cls.mydict. I’m on my phone so i can’t run and play with your example to give you a clear result.

Yes i tried it the thing is when creating a classmethod i dont get access to the instance only the class. So it doesnt work.
